# Can't boot ubuntu with USB swap inserted

Tags: boot, usb, flash, swap

I'm running ubuntu on some older hardware, it's working fine but I found it was much more usable with a spare 16GB flash drive used for swap.

I've set that up per the [instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173676/how-to-make-a-usb-stick-swap-disk) and it works fine; however, when I restart the device will not boot. I just get a flashing cursor. The only way I can get it to boot is to remove the flash drive. Any ideas? (it's not trying to boot from the USB as I've disabled USB as a boot device in the BIOS)

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: 20.04 Swap is a little different than 12.04. 20.04 makes it's own swapfile which requires an offset for hibernation. See if https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285207/how-do-you-hibernate-on-ubuntu-20-04/1285218#1285218 is any help to you. also even a fast USB3 drive is slower than a SSD. what does `sudo swapon -s` say?

Comment: It's version 20.04.1